# How to create a input tag have disable attribute in system.xml Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml

In my `system.xml`, i have a field tag as:

```
<field id="token" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
      <label>Auth Token</label>
</field>
```

What is attribute i need add to field tag for disable input in Configuration ?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think `<frontend_model>` works for you as like `Magento1`

```
<field id="recipient_email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Send Emails To</label>
    <validate>validate-email</validate>
    <frontend_model>YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Disable</frontend_model>
</field>
```

and your `frontend_model` class should be

```
<?php
namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Disable extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{    
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->setDisabled('disabled');
        return $element->getElementHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: how i can do this in dynamic rows field https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/321158/78648

Answer (score 15):

[Keyur Shah](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90824/42667)'s answer is correct but I found that it is not possible to copy the value of the disabled element. So instead of writing `$element->setDisabled('disabled');`
you can write `$element->setData('readonly', 1);`.
This displays the field the same way but you can mark the value and copy it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not supported by current XSD of system.xml (*Magento/Config/etc/system.xsd*).

To enable such behavior for all types of fields at once it is possible to extend `\Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field::render()` (e.g. using plugins) to make it support new `type` value of `attribute` element:

```
<field id="token" ...>
      <label>Auth Token</label>
      <attribute type="disabled">1</attribute>
</field>
```

At the moment it is possible to specify any value for `type` of `attribute` element, but only value `shared` will be processed, see `\Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form::_getSharedCssClass()`. Similar processing can be added in a new plugin to disable element if such `attribute` is specified.

Answer (score 0):

another way to disable your field, is to set the value in the `env.php` file.
The env.php allows you to set your configuration by default and disable the fields which are mapped in the `env.php` file. Your configuration could not be change by admin user. It's quite convenient if you want to put some sensitive settings.

```
'system' => [
   'default' => [
      'your_path => [
         'to_your' =>[
            'system_config =>['my special config in the store config']
          ],
       ],
   ]
]
```

Answer (score -3):

Try set all show* fields to 0

```
<field id="token" showInDefault="0" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
</field>
```

Comment: I want input tag disable, but if set attribute as you, it will hide

Comment: agree with @ThaoPham

Comment: @ThaoPham is correct