# How TO Add a TextArea in Dynamic Rows in System.xml

Tags: magento2

I want to add a Multiline Input "Textarea" in system.xml searched but not found if anyone can help me

thank you

**EDIT**

This is how I have created Dynamic Rows

```
use Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class SMSTemplates extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * @var SortOrder
     */
    private $orderStatusRenderer;
    
    /**
     * @var Status
     */
    private $statusRenderer;
    
    /**
     * @var Icons
     */
    private $templateRenderer;

    /**
     * Render Sort Order
     *
     * @return SortOrder
     */
    protected function getOrderStatusRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->orderStatusRenderer) {
            $this->orderStatusRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                OrderStatus::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->orderStatusRenderer;
    }
    /**
     * Render Status
     *
     * @return Status
     */
    protected function getStatusRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->statusRenderer) {
            $this->statusRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                Status::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->statusRenderer;
    }
    /**
     * Render Icons 
     *
     * @return Icons
     */
    protected function getTemplateRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->templateRenderer) {
            $this->templateRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                Tempalate::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->templateRenderer;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare rendering the new field by adding all the needed columns
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('order_status', 
            [
                'label' => __('Order Status'), 
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('status', 
            [
                'label' => __('Status'), 
                'renderer'  => $this->getStatusRenderer(),
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('template', 
            [
                'label' => __('Template'), 
                'class' => 'textarea',
                'style' => 'textarea'

            ]
        );
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }
    /**
     * Prepare existing row data object
     *
     * @param DataObject $row
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareArrayRow(DataObject $row)
    {
        $orderStatus = $row->getOrderStatus();
        $options = []; 
        if($orderStatus != Null ){
            $status = $row->getStatus();    
            $options['option_' . $this->getStatusRenderer()->calcOptionHash($status)] = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        $orderStatus = $row->getStatus();
        if($_FILES != Null){    
            $options['option_' . $this->getOrderStatusRenderer()->calcOptionHash($orderStatus)] = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        $template = $row->getTemplate();
        if($template != Null){  
            $options['option_' . $this->getTemplateRenderer()->calcOptionHash($template)] = 'selected="selected"';
        }   
        $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
    }

    /**
     * Render Feilds Styling
     *
     * @param array $columnName
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function renderCellTemplate($columnName)
    {
        if ($columnName == "order_status") {
            $this->_columns[$columnName]['class'] = 'input-text required-entry';
            $this->_columns[$columnName]['style'] = 'width:150px';
        }elseif ($columnName == "template") {
            $this->_columns[$columnName]['class'] = 'input-text required-entry';
            $this->_columns[$columnName]['style'] = 'width:200px; height:200px;';
        }
        return parent::renderCellTemplate($columnName);
    }
}
```

Here is My System.xml

```
<group id="sms_templates_settings" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
     <label>SMS Templates</label>
     <field id="sms_templates" translate="label" sortOrder="101" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <label></label>
                <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\SMSTemplates</frontend_model>
                    <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\SMSTemplates</backend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
```

this is how its Gernating but I need last field to me multline

[image]

Comment: Please share your code how you're generating dynamic rows

Comment: please see question now

Comment: can you please share system.xml so I can generate same on my system

Comment: i have edited again please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an idea from this one
https://gist.github.com/ianitsky/852d4d51bd559612235e8c0c7fbc8e76

You have to do the same as you have done for dropdown

OK Please check this

Please change namespace and class of your choice I am putting example

In your case please add this in SMSTemplates

```
/**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    private function textAreaTypes()
    {
        if (!$this->textAreaType) {
            $this->textAreaType = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                '\Nilesh\Prefech\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Textarea',
                ''
            );
        }

        return $this->textAreaType;
    }

$this->addColumn(
            'sort_order',
            [
                'label' => __('Sort Order'),
                'renderer' => $this->textAreaTypes()
            ]
        );
```

Render file

```
<?php    
namespace Nilesh\Prefech\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;
    
    // use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context;
    
    class Textarea extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function _toHtml()
        {
            $inputName = $this->getInputName();
            $columnName = $this->getColumnName();
            $column = $this->getColumn();
    
            return '<textarea id="' . $this->getInputId().'" name="' . $inputName . '" ' .
                ($column['size'] ? 'size="' . $column['size'] . '"' : '') . ' class="' .
                (isset($column['class']) ? $column['class'] : 'input-text') . '"'.
                (isset($column['style']) ? ' style="'.$column['style'] . '"' : '') . '></textarea>';
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: i have no idea of Magento 1 can you please convert that code for me in Magento 2 ? thank you

Comment: Please see it might help you

Comment: thank you so much its working perfectly fine